# вычислить сумму натуральных чисел от 1 до n

Tags: c

Вычислить сумму натуральных чисел от 1 до n. Использовать формулу арифметической прогрессии нельзя (N*(N +1)/2).

Не знаю, даже как продолжить...

Заранее спасибо.

Получилось вот так:

```
int main(void)
{
int i,n,s; // целочисленный тип данных. ввод переменных.
n=5; // переменная n
s=0; // переменная для хранения суммы ряда цикла
for (i=1; i<n+1; i++) // счетчик от 1 до 5 (n)    {
printf("%d ",i); // вывод - ряд 1 2 3 4 5 
}
//write         // записать полученное значение?
s=i;//сложить ряд не используя формулу геометрической прогрессии?
printf("s = %d",s);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `s = s + i;` в вашем цикле c printf? И никаких `s = i;` после него

Answer (score 1):

Может как-то так?

```
int main(void)
{
int i,n,s; // целочисленный тип данных. ввод переменных.
n=5; // переменная n
s=0; // переменная для хранения суммы ряда цикла
for (i=1; i<n+1; i++) // счетчик от 1 до 5 (n)    {
printf("%d ",i); // вывод - ряд 1 2 3 4 5 
s=s+i; // делаем сумму всех чисел ряда не используя формулу геометрической прогрессии
}
//write         // записать полученное значение?
printf("s = ",s);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("s = ",s);`  " ... %d\n" добавьте

Comment: Переполнение целого.